# Wordpress - Create a slug for image files

Tags: wordpress, seo

So here's the deal:

I need to make all posted images in wordpress have seo-friendly urls, much like slugs for a post. So, if I attach an image 'foo01234.jpg' with a title of "Foo Bar Image" to a post, instead of storing the image as '/2011/09/foo01234.jpg', I want to save it as '/2011/09/foo-bar-image.jpg'.

Is there a way to hook in to a post update in order to achieve this?

Comment: Found a plugin, [Rename Media](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rename-media/), that accomplishes this task, for anyone else who is looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try this: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/slug4apig/

Comment: Thanks. looks like a good alternative to Rename Media, which I listed above. Appreciate the help.